# Regex not working for checking length

Tags: jquery, regex

For a long time I have been using the regex in one of my forms(java , jQuery project). Since I had nothing to do with special characters, I had a simple regex as follows:

```
 pattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,11}$/i;
```

But now I do care for special ones and modified it as:

```
pattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9-@_]{1,11}$/i;
```

However, with more upcoming issues now it seems better to handle all the special character. So I tried looking for something on net that handles all known characters, but no luck. DO anyone of you ever came across something of that sort. I guess not?

Secondly I decided to allow everything within a range of 11 characters. I tried following:

```
 pattern = /^[]{1,11}$;
  pattern = /^{1,11}$;
```

I don't get it working. Although I don't want to check the length of string. Can this be done simply with a regex. i.e. checking just the length of input string regardless of what you enter.

Any help appreciated please

Comment: `9-@` is a range. Put `-` as the very last character or escape it with a back slash

Comment: Did you try: `pattern = /^.{1,11}$/;`

Comment: @zerkms uh, strange; do you mean that in the JS regex engine, ranges are evaluated left to right? What character will match if you write a character class such as `[a-e-x]`? `a`, or a `-`, or any char beween `e` and `x` or any char between `a` and `e`, or a `-`, or a `x`?

Comment: @fge: that's what I don't believe as well, it's just a guess after OP's "now it seems better to handle all the special character"

Answer (score 1):

The hyphen needs to be escaped because of its position inside of the character class.

```
pattern = /^[a-z0-9\-@_]{1,11}$/i;
```

**Note:** Inside of a character class the hyphen has special meaning. You can place it as the first or last character of the class. In some regex implementations, you can also place directly after a range. If you place the hyphen anywhere else you need to precede it with a backslash in order to add it to your character class.

You could write your regular expression like this since `\w` matches `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` ...

```
pattern = /^[\w@-]{1,11}$/;
```

Comment: perhaps you didn't get me right. I want a regex that should allow everything as far as the length is below 11. Or in other words I am looking for a substitute of `$('#input').val().length<=11`

Answer (score 0):

Simply try this:

```
pattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9\@\_\-]{1,11}$/i;
```

That will accept between 1 and 11 times one character from this regex.